# Printing out all json objects, including picture?

Tags: jquery, json

I need some help trying to print all of the JSON objects when I click the "alleLand" button, which includes name, town and a picture. Really new to using JSON, so I don't really know what I'm doing. Hoping someone can help!

```
<body>
    <div>
        <h3 id="header">Mitt feriested</h3>
        <label>Land:
            <input id="land" type="text">
        </label>
        <input id="sokLand" class="landBtn" type="button" value="Søk etter land">
        <input id="alleLand" class="landBtn "type="button" value="Velg alle destinasjoner">
    </div>     

    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var feriestederJSON = { landliste: [
            {"land": "Tyskland", 
             "by": "Munchen", 
             "bildeAvBy": "munchen.jpg"
            },
            {"land": "Tyskland", 
             "by": "Berlin", 
             "bildeAvBy": "berlin.jpg"
            },
            {"land": "Spania", 
             "by": "Barcelona", 
             "bildeAvBy": "barcelone.jpg"
            },
            {"land": "Spania", 
             "by": "Palma", 
             "bildeAvBy": "palma.jpg"
            },
            {"land": "Norge", 
             "by": "Oslo", 
             "bildeAvBy": "oslo.jpg"
            },
            {"land": "Norge", 
             "by": "Bergen", 
             "bildeAvBy": "bergen.jpg"
            },
        ]};

        $(function() {
          $(document).on('click','#alleLand',function() {
              var antallLand = feriestederJSON.landliste.length;
              for(var i = 0; i < antallLand; i++){
                  var land = feriestederJSON.landliste[i].land;
                  var by = feriestederJSON.landliste[i].by;
                  var bildeAvBy = feriestederJSON.landliste[i].bildeAvBy;
              }
          });
        }
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: What is meant by "print" exactly? Writing HTML to the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply make a new element that you'll use to hold your list, make a new javascript variable outside the loop and append the html string you want to show into it.
Then replace the innerHTML of the element you've created with the variable.

Example element:

```
<ul id="land_list"></ul>
```

Addition to code:

```
    var output_html = '';

    for(var i = 0; i < antallLand; i++){
        var land = feriestederJSON.landliste[i].land;
        var by = feriestederJSON.landliste[i].by;
        var bildeAvBy = feriestederJSON.landliste[i].bildeAvBy;

        output_html += '<li>' + land + ', ' + by + ', <img src="' + bildeAvBy + '" /></li>';            
    }

    document.querySelector("#land_list").innerHTML = output_html;
```

**Edit - since the code doesn't run:**
It would be better to use onclick on the element itself or a JavaScript based event listener instead of a jQuery based event listener. Move the listing method into a function and run the function on click.

```
<input id="alleLand" class="landBtn "type="button" value="Velg alle destinasjoner" onclick="list_json_data();">
```

Javascript:

```
function list_json_data() {
   var feriestederJSON ... // Make sure to replace this
   var output_html = '';

    for(var i = 0; i < antallLand; i++){
        var land = feriestederJSON.landliste[i].land;
        var by = feriestederJSON.landliste[i].by;
        var bildeAvBy = feriestederJSON.landliste[i].bildeAvBy;

        output_html += '<li>' + land + ', ' + by + ', <img src="' + bildeAvBy + '" /></li>';            
    }

    document.querySelector("#land_list").innerHTML = output_html;
}
```

Comment: I can't get this to work. I still don't get any output when I press the alleLand button. Eventhough everything looks right.

Comment: @SophieParker added additional info to solution

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems right this far. You want to print it using printer or simply want to see it in webpage as html .?
 To output it in html element, say a div you can simply add a line to append results in that div. 
Your code may be as below:

```js
$(function() {
          $(document).on('click','#alleLand',function() {
              var antallLand = feriestederJSON.landliste.length;
              for(var i = 0; i < antallLand; i++){
                  var land = feriestederJSON.landliste[i].land;
                  var by = feriestederJSON.landliste[i].by;
                  var bildeAvBy = feriestederJSON.landliste[i].bildeAvBy;
                   $('#DivOutPut').append(land + '<br />' + by+'<br />'+bildeAvBy + '<br />' + '<br />' );
              }
          });
```

```html
<div id="DivOutPut"></div>
```

Comment: I want to see it in the webpage as html. But I don't get any output no matter what I press at this point.

Comment: Just add an html element, say a div  in which you want to out put the results and append everything in it.